# PHP $_GET is empty when the url has variables passed

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, header

this is my first stack overflow question.
I have a home page, where you can login, if you login it sends you to a login php in which you have some code that checks if login is incorrect. If that is the case this code redirects you back to home page:

`header("Location: ".SERVER_ADDRESS."home?error=invalid_login");`

Now you are back on the home page but the url variable is not set. It does not show in a
`var_dump(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));` or
`var_dump($_GET);`

This is my index.php file:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once("config.php");

if(!(isset($_GET['page']))) { // redirect to main page 
    
    header("Location: ".SERVER_ADDRESS."home");
    
} else {
    
    $mp = new MainPage($_GET['page']); // redirect to given page
    
}

?>
```

If you go try login again with wrong credentials and do the same redirection process it will now show the variable.
Same thing happens if I were to refresh the header after few seconds.

I seem to not understand why the home page would not show the variable straight away, I just want to use the variable for an if statement that would print an extra invalid login message.

I am using wampserver64 for localhosting.

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-\#]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

EDIT:
CBroe's answer helped me, my htaccess did not have a QSA flag

Comment: Your rule matches on `home`, and rewrites the request to `/index.php?page=home`. You need to add the QSA flag - query string append - to get the new query string you are creating there, merged with any existing one.

Comment: That alone would not explain how it works the second time or after a refresh though. Maybe you have an additional caching issue. And `#` in your rule pattern character class is pretty superfluous by the way, you will never encounter that character in a URL path. (RewriteRule only matches against the path component of the URL.)

Comment: It does rewrite to /home but the second time that is also the case, which could mean that it could potentially be a caching issue?
This is a `var_dump(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` after the initial login:
`'scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
  'host' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
  'path' => string '/gra/home' (length=9)`
after second time:
`'scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
  'host' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
  'path' => string '/gra/home' (length=9)
  'query' => string 'error=invalid_login' (length=19)`

Comment: This page must not be resolved by a comment and an edit of the question.  SHNXG or @CBroe should post an answer so that this page is resolved officially/properly.  (Also, all comments containing relevant question details should be removed.  All irrelevant comments (including mine) should be removed.)

Answer (score 1):

Your rule matches on `home`, and rewrites the request to `/index.php?page=home`.

You need to add the `QSA` flag - query string append - to get the new query string you are creating there, merged with any existing one.